# Why can't I install anything in the application center?

Tags: appcenter, package

When I want to download anything in the application center, the following phrase appears:

```
Error while installing package: installed amavisd-new package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Did you have a previous app installation that went wrong? You can try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f`. The first will reconfigure the database and the second will try to repair any broken installations.

Answer (score 0):

When I used these two commands, these commands appeared to me in both of them :

[image: The commands that appeared to me]

Answer (score 0):

The `amavisd` log suggests that your system hostname is not a fully-qualified domain name (FQDN). What does

```
$ hostnamectl status
```

and/or

```
$ cat /etc/hostname
```

tell you? You may need to change it (via `hostnamectl` or by editing `/etc/hostname`, respectively) to a resolvable domain name, i.e., `yourdomain.tld`.